# Semantic-UI, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Can anyone figure this out, I can't get the modal to work. Browser console shows this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

I tried uncommenting `Query.noConflict();` and `jQuery(function($){}`, but it's not making any difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="http://oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.0.4/components/modal.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="http://oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.0.4/components/button.min.css">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <button class="ui button">Test</button>

        <div class="ui modal my-dialog">
          <i class="close icon"></i>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="description">
              <div class="ui header">Text stuff here.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui black deny button">
              Nope
            </div>
            <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
              Yep, that's me
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                console.log( "document loaded" );
                // jQuery.noConflict();

                // Your jQuery code here, using the $
                // jQuery(function($){                  
                    $('.ui.modal.my-dialog')
                        .modal('show');
                // });              
            });                         
        </script
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've included the **CSS** of the plugin, but not its JavaScript. You need to include the JavaScript as well (after the script tag including jQuery).